# React Rxjs: catchError doesn't return data from backend

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

I'm using Rxjs with React (TS) and in my epics I have switchMap where I call an API. Then is map and catchErrors and I want to pass error response to my reducer but it doesn't work.

I found this example: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html

so I used it:

```
switchMap((action) => from(Currencies.getAll(action.payload)).pipe(
    map((currencies: any) => {
        return ({type: FETCH_CURRENCIES_SUCCESS, payload: {
            name: action.payload,
            currencies: currencies,
        }});
    }),
    catchError(error => of({
        type: SEND_CURRENCIES_ERROR,
        payload: error.xhr.response,
        error: true,
    }))
))
```

and my backend returns 422 code with errors. It's reaching catchErrors and pass payload to reducer but then if I do console.log I see standard Error message:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

In network tab I see that red request and in "Preview" tab are errors, status, title etc. returned from backend. How to get this data in my epic?

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it was a stupid thing. I'm using axios in my project and in error response there is no xhr object obviously. Just replace payload in catchError to:

```
payload: error.response.data,
```